# SED with "unmatched /" and odd behavior

Tags: sed, null

I have an input file that looks like this, and i was trying a couple transformations with sed :

Original File :

```
DATA: gt_alv LIKF zfica_paym_cancel_alv OCCURS 0 WITH HFADFR LINF.
DATA: gt_out LIKF zfica_paym_cancel_out OCCURS 0 WITH HFADFR LINF.
```

I want to clean some characters based on their hexadecimal values, but i m getting an odd behavior from the box. ( Ran in MobaXterm )

When i run :

```
sed -e $'s/\x20/\x040/g' testsed.txt
```

the output is :

```
DATA:0gt_alv0LIKE0zfica_paym_cancel_alv0OCCURS000WITH0HEADER0LINE.
DATA:0gt_out0LIKE0zfica_paym_cancel_out0OCCURS000WITH0HEADER0LINE.
```

and it works as intended. But when i try to hit the null value x00 i get the following error :

```
sed -e $'s/\x00/\x040/g' testsed.txt
```

produces :

```
sed: unmatched '/'
```

I have tried various combination. Giving the ascii codes in octal doesnt work at all. But hex numbers work just find expect from the /x00 null. Can someone explain to me why this happens and if possible how to resolve it? Is it a problem with Moba? Thank you.

Comment: Why did you put a `$` in front of the pattern?

Comment: It should work without the `$` : `sed -e 's/\x00/\x040/g' testsed.txt`.

Comment: Without the $ it doesnt do any transformation at all. That's why i used the $ in the first place, because for some reason without it it cant expand the hex numbers on Moba.

Comment: @Kenavoz - the `$` at the start of the pattern makes this a format expansion, which works in a number of shells. WIthout it, it's up to `sed` to interpret the special characters. GNU sed has some support for printf expansion, but it's incomplete, and even then, GNU sed is only included by default on a limited number of operating systems. Better to have a solution that is more portable.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov That's a Bash "C-style" string.

Comment: "Moba" apparently refers to MobaXterm which is a Windows ... thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
>   string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>   ANSI C standard.

From : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html

You should try to escape the `\` in your pattern :

```
sed -e $'s/\\x00/\x040/g' null.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot have a NUL byte in a shell string because it signals end of string to the underlying C library.  Use a tool which handles internal NUL bytes in strings correctly.

```
perl -pe 's/\x00/\x40/g' testsed.txt
```